# MySQL - Select All Except what is in this Table

Tags: sql, mysql

I am wanting to select all images that a user does not already have.

I have three tables: `user`, `image`, and `user_image`:

- _user (id, user, pass)
- _image (id, data)
- _user_image (id, user_id, image_id)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Using `LEFT JOIN/IS NULL`

---

```
   SELECT DISTINCT
          i.data
     FROM IMAGE i
     JOIN USER_IMAGE ui ON ui.image_id = i.id
LEFT JOIN USER u ON u.id = ui.user_id
                AND u.user = ?
    WHERE u.id IS NULL
```

### Using `NOT IN`

---

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       i.data
  FROM IMAGE i
  JOIN USER_IMAGE ui ON ui.image_id = i.id
 WHERE ui.user_id NOT IN (SELECT u.id
                            FROM USER u
                           WHERE u.user = ?)
```

### Using `NOT EXISTS`

---

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       i.data
  FROM IMAGE i
  JOIN USER_IMAGE ui ON ui.image_id = i.id
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT NULL
                    FROM USER u
                   WHERE u.id = ui.user_id
                     AND u.user = ?)
```

### Performance:

---

The `LEFT JOIN/IS NULL` and `NOT IN` provide equivalent performance - the `NOT EXISTS` is ~30% less efficient.  [See this for more details](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/).

Comment: The `LEFT JOIN/IS NULL` can be done with one less join and without `DISTINCT`. Have a peek at my solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it pretty easily with a subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM image WHERE id NOT IN 
    (SELECT image_id FROM user_image WHERE user_id = THE_USER_ID);
```

Comment: Would upvote if i could. I'm at the daily limit.
You could also do instead of `NOT`, in the subquery write `!=`.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from _image where id not in (select image_id from _user_image where user_id = ?)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT
    i.*
FROM
    _image i
    LEFT JOIN _user_image u ON u.image_id = i.id
WHERE
    u.user_id != <user-id>
```

Answer (score 0):

select id, date from image where id not in (select image_id from  user_image where user_id =

There is a faster way but this is easier to follow.

Another way would be:

select id, data from image left join user_image on user.id=user_image.user_id where user_image.id = null