# query only returns one value and it should return 2

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following tables.

```
CREATE TABLE `Customer` (
`CID` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`Name` varchar(40) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`City` varchar(40) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`State` varchar(40) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 PRIMARY KEY (`CID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_bin;

CREATE TABLE `LineItem` (
`LID` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`OID` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`PID` varchar(110) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`Number` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`TotalPrice` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`LID`),
KEY `Order ID` (`OID`),
CONSTRAINT `Order ID` FOREIGN KEY (`OID`) REFERENCES `OrderItem` (`OID`) ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
CREATE TABLE `OrderItem` (
`OID` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`CID` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
PRIMARY KEY (`OID`),
KEY `CID` (`CID`),
CONSTRAINT `CID` FOREIGN KEY (`CID`) REFERENCES `Customer` (`CID`) ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
CREATE TABLE `Product` (
`PID` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`ProductName` varchar(40) DEFAULT '',
`Price` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`PID`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

What I've been trying to do in my query is run it so I can successfully get it to do the following:

1. List the products bought by all the customers of Newark
2. List the products ordered only by the customers of Newark

For #5, I tried this query:

```
Select product.productname
From Customer as c INNER JOIN OrderItem as o
ON c.CID = o.CID
INNER JOIN LineItem line
ON o.OID = line.OID
Inner Join Product product
ON line.PID = product.PID
Where C.City = 'Newark'
Having Count(product.productname) > 1;
```

But it only returns one value and it should return 2 (unless I am not using it properly).

For #6 I understand the concept but I don't know how to "subtract tables" in SQL.

The goal of the first question is to list the common items purchased by everyone from Newark.  So if Person A bought Items X, Y and Z and Person B bought W, V, and Y, the query will return "Item Y".

Comment: step 1 for help is a better question title.  Please re-read what you posted and think a bit about who would read it and why.  A good title is key to getting _you_ the answer(s) that _you_ seek.

Comment: so I made the first attempt at that for you.

Comment: Was trying to get all of the duplicate entries to show.  I have two people from Newark and was trying to show the item(s) that both of them purchased.

Comment: Having count(*) > 1; Is that what you are trying to use to limit to 2 records? If so...thats wrong. A having clause is a filter on an aggregate and requires a group by to work...any other database would return an error on what you have here, but MySQL happily does the wrong thing instead of returning an error.  From your comment above...try adding a group by

Comment: There are 5 records.  3 of the records are unique.  What I want is two of the 3 records (the ones which are repeated) to be listed.

Comment: Thank you Twelfth.  I assume that the query can be done in multiple ways but adding the groupby productname yielded me the answer.

Comment: Can you include the 5 records?

Comment: @Jenn the 5 records would be computer, scanner, gaming console, computer, scanner.  The query would successfully report just scanner and computer.

Comment: It looks like you are missing a group by in your query. After `Where C.City = 'Newark'` it should say `Group by product.productname`

Comment: Yes.  @Twelfth mentioned that and I corrected it I just didn't notify him properly.

Comment: Just a thought. This is probably something that you could have debugged yourself by temporarily removing the `Having` and then adding `Count(product.productname)` in the select. You would have seen a lot more 1s than you were anticipating.

Comment: Would this method only have worked if I knew how many customers there were in the city in question?

Comment: What are #5 and #6? Are they 1. and 2?

Comment: There is no QUESTION in the question. There is some illegal query syntax but no SPECIFICATION for a correct version.

Answer (score 2):

I guess my comment is an answer.

```
Having Count(product.productname) > 1;
```

Having requires a group by to function correctly as it's a filter on an aggregate and aggregates require a group by.  90% of database engines would have returned an error explicitly stating it requires a group by...but MySQL prefers to do the wrong thing instead of return an error to you (it's why you got one row...MySQL did a group by of whatever it felt like).  Add a group by (I assume on product name with what you have here) and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

you need to add GROUP BY . Try this:

```
   Select product.productname
   From Customer as c 
   INNER JOIN OrderItem as o ON c.CID = o.CID
   INNER JOIN LineItem line ON o.OID = line.OID
   Inner Join Product product ON line.PID = product.PID
   Where C.City = 'Newark'
   Group by product.productname
   Having Count(*) > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Two other answers have pointed out that if you want the HAVING then you need a GROUP BY. But your question doesn't actually ask a question or explain what your query is supposed to return. (You are not explaining clearly in your question or comments.) You wrote a comment, "I have two people from Newark and was trying to show the item(s) [product(s)?] that both of them purchased." But if your query is only "corrected" with grouping then it calculates the wrong counts.

A problem is that you should return PID (and maybe ProductName). You need to list products. PIDs as key are presumably 1:1 with products but ProductName is not a key so product names are not 1:1 with products. ProductName can even be NULL. So selecting ProductName does not get you all the relevant products. (Also in LineItem PID should be a FOREIGN KEY.)

Another problem is that you should use PID to GROUP BY product. ProductName is not a key of Product. So two products can have the same name. So you will get the count for each product name, not for each product. Plus ProductName can be NULL. (Even if you were only returning the names not PIDs of products with those counts, you would need to group by PID.)

Another problem is the counts are wrong. Grouping by PID groups rows that can be made by combining a Newark Customer row, an OrderItem row and a LineItem row for a product. Those combination rows are counted by COUNT(PID). But you want the number of disinct Newark customers in those rows. You could do this by a sub-select but there happens to be a shorter way.

```
SELECT p.PID, p.ProductName
FROM Customer c
JOIN OrderItem AS o ON c.CID = o.CID
JOIN LineItem l ON o.OID = l.OID
JOIN Product p ON l.PID = p.PID
WHERE c.City = 'Newark'
GROUP BY (p.PID)
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT c.CID) > 1;
```

You get a query for goal 1 after a change in part of its condition.

```
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT c.CID)
    = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Customer WHERE City='Newark')
```

Relational algebra MINUS/DIFFERENCE corresponds to EXCEPT in the SQL standard. But MySQL does not have it. You can do it using [LEFT JOIN, NOT IN or NOT EXISTS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2106400/3404097) instead.