# SQL Query is running for hours

Tags: sql-server, subquery, inner-join

This query is running for hours, looking for help making it more efficient.  I've played around and what seems to make it run so slowly is the last part of the WHERE clause:

`"AND emp.employee_ID NOT IN <subquery with INNER JOINS and WHERE clause>".`

If I comment out that part, it returns in seconds, but unfortunately I need to omit those records from the parent query, so I need some logic which does that.  Any other approaches appreciated.  SQL Query Analyzer suggests an index on the employeejob table I believe.

I cannot change the select list, this query sends data to a website and it has to be in that exact format.

This query does not just run once.  Its select clause will vary slightly (Part Time will change to Full Time for example) and it will run again inside a loop.  The @Reporting_Date will change to another month and it will run again inside the loop.  All in all this query will run dozens of times (over a series of several months, each month with a slightly different metric like Part Time, Full Time, Exempt, Non Exempt).  I left the loop logic out, since it's basically the same query repeating.  It seems to take hours just to return once month, for one metric.

Here is the exact code:

```
DECLARE @Reporting_Date varchar(20)
DECLARE @Metric_Date varchar(20)
DECLARE @Begin_Date varchar(20)
DECLARE @End_Date varchar(20)

SET @Reporting_Date = cast('02/01/2015' as datetime)
SET @Metric_Date = convert(varchar,dateadd(m, -1 ,@Reporting_Date),112)
SET @Begin_Date = convert(varchar,dateadd(m, -1 ,@Reporting_Date),112)
SET @End_Date = convert(varchar,dateadd(d, -1 ,@Reporting_Date),112)

select @Metric_Date as MetricPeriod
            ,org.locationnameid
            ,dep.divisionid
            ,ej.jobdepartmentid
            ,1
            ,'     Part Time'
            ,3
            ,Count(*)
        from ddw.dbo.Employee emp
            inner join dbo.Organization org on org.organizationid = emp.organizationid and org.orgid in ('A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z')
            inner join dbo.status st on st.statusid = emp.statusid and st.statuscode not in ('T','X','N')
            inner join dbo.employeejob ej on ej.employeeid = emp.employeeid and ej.jobnumber = '1' and ej.SnapShotDate = @Metric_Date
            inner join dbo.department dep on dep.departmentid = ej.jobdepartmentid
        where
            ej.percentfulltime between '2.00' and '89.00'
            AND
            emp.SnapShotDate = @Metric_Date
            **AND
                emp.Employee_ID not IN 
                    (
                    select Employee_ID 
                    from dbo.Employee_Terms_All terms
                    inner join dbo.Organization org on org.organizationid = terms.organizationid and org.orgid in ('A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z')
                    inner join dbo.terminationreasoncode trc on trc.terminationreasoncodeid = terms.terminationreasoncodeid and trc.terminationreasoncode not in ('4','5','6')
                    inner join dbo.department dep on dep.departmentid = terms.jobdepartmentid
                    where terms.terminationdate between @Begin_Date and @End_Date
                    )**
        group by 
            org.locationnameid
            ,dep.divisionid
            ,ej.jobdepartmentid
        order by 
            org.locationnameid
            ,dep.divisionid
            ,ej.jobdepartmentid
```

Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: There are tons of inner joins and nested queries, which is why it is taking forever.  doing joins on joins will cause you nightmares

Comment: Also your orgid in clause is checking for every letter of the alphabet. What are the possible values for this?

Comment: So add the suggested index.. what happens? (Note the percentage of time the 'non-indexed' / suggested replacement portion of the query takes - if it is significant it is a clear first-round winner.)

Comment: @holtc Maybe you're not used to a real SQL database *:whistle:* (I kid a bit, but the number of joins isn't so much an issue as the ability for them to be correctly/efficiently decomposed in RA with applied indices.)

Comment: So have you acted on the suggestion of creating an index, and maybe more than just the suggested index?

Comment: Something you could try (and it could make things worse, but you my want to give it a try), is to reformulate the `NOT IN` as a `NOT EXISTS`. In order to do that, you would add ` AND Employee_id = emp.Employee_ID ` to the `WHERE` inside the parens after NOT EXISTS. For this to potentially help your query, it would be very important that `Employee_ID` (in, presumably, Employee_Terms_All) have an index on it.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2106400/3404097) re interchanging LEFT JOIN, NOT EXISTS and NOT IN. When available you can also use standard SQL EXCEPT aka Oracle MINUS.

Comment: In addition to the suggestions above: add `GROUP BY Employee_ID ` to your subquery.

Comment: NOT IN are usually very expensive. Try to avoid it as possible as you can. Sometime you can create a temp table (a subquery) of the opposite result first and then do a join on the temp table.

Answer (score 1):

**1st Path**
well in order to understand the bottleneck of yout query, I will split the problem:
1/ select contains a count(*)
will count this records after doing 2/ and 1/

2/ from Employees (contains a lot of iner join)
will copy all this join in a employee_join_temp table

3/ EmployeesID calculater list
will copy all requiered id in employeesID_temp table

=> Doing so will make you understand what is heavy.
=> Doing so will make you split the job, and split the time (if running in // systems)

**2nd Path**
If that is not quick enought, I will go to : MAP/REDUICE
1/ prepare all datas (export / import)
2/ cleanup datas
3/ map reduice in order to perform this queries in RAM.

Once a query is slow, if tuning indexes, splitting jobs is not working, you should better to go for a clean version Map/reduice than to loose time.

**Choose your path! :)**