# Join table before or after except

Tags: sql, outer-join

I have two data tables, the top table is Products and the bottom table is Categories.

[image]

In the products table, I have products that do not have every categoryID such a 3 and 7. I have found this out by using this statement.

```
Select CategoryID
From Categories 
Except
Select CategoryID
From Products
```

Which yields this result

[image]

I would like to include the categoryName and Description into my above query. Can I take this query and Join a table onto it to get my expected output? If not how can I use an `Outer Join` to achieve my end result rather than `Except`?

Comment: MySQL doesn't support `EXCEPT`, so I'm wondering which database you actually used to generate these results.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL - Select All Except what is in this Table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2106372/mysql-select-all-except-what-is-in-this-table)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what database you used to generate the results you showed us, because AFAIK MySQL doesn't support `EXCEPT`.  But your question is answerable; you can do a `LEFT JOIN` between the two tables to arrive at the same result:

```
SELECT t1.CategoryID
FROM Categories t1
LEFT JOIN Products t2
    ON t1.CategoryID = t2.CategoryID
WHERE t2.CategoryID IS NULL       -- NULL indicates the Categories record did not match
```

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding on tags. I was close with my own answers but I didn't know `NULL` could be used in that sense.

Answer (score 2):

In SQL You can use this. but this is only show ID is only in Categories Table. its not show Products table

```
Select categoryName, Description
From Products
where id = ( Select CategoryID
             From Categories 
             Except
             Select CategoryID
             From Products )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CategoryID,CategoryName,Description
FROM Categories t1
where CategoryId not in(select p.CategoryID from Products p)
```